# Is there a function $f\in C^\infty([0, \infty), \mathbb R)$ with the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

is there a function $f\in C^\infty([0, \infty), \mathbb R)$ such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0,$$ and $e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)=e^{-t^2-2tx}$ for every $t\in [0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

Plugging in $t = 0$ gives $e^0 f(x) - f(x) = e^0$, which simplifies to $0 = 1$.  Ergo, no such function can exist.

Comment: Cool, what If I suppose $t>0$?

Comment: @PtF Continuity would still imply no such $f$.  You'd have, for a fixed $x$, $f(x) = e^{-t^2 - 2tx} (f(x+t) - 1)$, so taking the limit as $t \to 0$ $f(x) = f(x) - 1$, $0 = 1$ as before.

Comment: Thanks for the help... Indeed I was looking for a function $f\in C([0, \infty))$ such that, $$\sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)|=1,$$ but I got nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: take $x=0$, then $e^{-t^2}f(t) = f(0)+e^{-t^2}$, which gives you$$f(t) = 1+e^{t^2}f(0).$$ whatever the initial condition, your function can't vanish on inifnity.